Link catalog with Whatsapp Business Account through API
I have created a catalog and connected it using this document but I want to do it with API now. I know how upload products using feed API but I cannot find any API endpoint to connect the catalog to a particular WABA account. Is there something that I am missing here?

This one here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/product_catalogs/#Creating

Thank you for answering! But its just for creating the catalog, a business can have multiple catalogs created but only one of them can actually be linked to a WABA. I am looking for an endpoint that can link a catalog to a WABA.

To link a product catalog to a WhatsApp Business Account (WABA) via the Meta Graph API, use the following POST request:
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/<WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-ID>/product_catalogs' \
--form 'catalog_id="<CATALOG-ID>"' \
--form 'access_token="<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>"'

Replace <WHATSAPP-BUSINESS-ID>, <CATALOG-ID>, and <YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN> with your WABA ID, catalog ID, and a valid access token, respectively.
Required Permissions:
Ensure your access token includes both whatsapp_business_management and catalog_management permissions to successfully link the catalog to your WABA.

use Get request by passing same form fields in query params, then you will get the catalog id and name connected to whatsapp-business-account (passed in url)

This works! Do you know how to create a catalog? I am using this end point but I keep getting this error message": Unsupported post request. Object with ID xyz does not exist, missing permissions.. These are my permissions: catalog_management, ads_management, business_management, whatsapp_business_management, commerce_account_read_settings, commerce_account_manage_orders, commerce_account_read_orders, whatsapp_business_messaging and I can see my owned catalogs but cannot create. Thankyou for your help!

yes, pass name and access_token in body  , and use url like
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0//owned_product_catalogs
